# Div does not stay where I put it

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

So, I made this page that finds different customers and loads the data for each customer. the data is in a collapsible div and the bottom set of data hangs over the modal. Here is the code I wrote.

```
echo'<div id="findCustByFirstNameModal" class="modal modal-message modal-success fade" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"  style="width: 600px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-title">Success</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel-heading">
            ';
                    foreach($test as $key => $val)
                    {
                        $custNum= $test[$key]["customerNumber"];
                        if($prevCustNum!=$custNum)
                        {
                            echo'
                    <a class="panel-title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-'.$test[$key]["customerNumber"].'" href="#panel-element-'.$test[$key]["customerNumber"].'">
                        <table class="table" style="background-color: light-gray">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Customer Number:</td><td>'.$test[$key]["customerNumber"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name:</td><td>'.$test[$key]["firstName"].' '.$test[$key]["lastName"].'</td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="panel-element-'.$test[$key]['customerNumber'].'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                                ';
                                foreach($test as $key => $val)
                            {
                                if($test[$key]["customerNumber"] == $custNum)
                                {
                                    echo'


                            <tr><td>Ticket Number:</td><td class="fontBlue"><form action="aap.php" method="POST"><input type="submit" id="submitButtonLink" name="ticketNumber" value="'.$test[$key]["ticketNumber"].'"></form></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Description:</td><td>'.substr($test[$key]["issueDescription"], 0, 40).'</td></tr>
                                ';
                                }   
                            }
            echo'
                        </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding:30px;">
                </div>
                ';
        }
            $prevCustNum= $custNum;
    }

    echo'
                </div> <!-- / .modal-body -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
        </div> <!-- / .modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- / .modal-dialog -->
    </div>
';
```

and this is what happens
[image]

In this screenshot of the page source you can see that the end div tag was moved just under the last customer name right before the ticket information.

[image]

Everything lines up in the code, so I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: You are starting `<div class="panel-heading">` outside of your first `foreach`, but you are ending it inside.  That's probably going to mess things up.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. If you want to post that as the answer I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You output `<div class="panel-heading">` immediately before your first `foreach` loop.  You then have `</div>` within the loop, but have not opened any new `<div>`.  This means that the `</div>` within the loop is closing the `<div class="panel-heading">` created outside of the loop.  This is going to cause a tag mismatch and likely create some pretty unexpected results.